# Scatter plot references row numbers rather than selected data

Tags: excel, vba, graph, auto-update

EDIT: The problem is that the scatter graph is plotting my data against the row number, rather than the selected x-axis. When i change to a line graph, it does it correctly, but my VBA only works on scatter plots so i need to either make this graph reference the correct data or alter my code to make it work on line charts. I checked that the data is formatted as numbers, not text, but still no improvements.

I created a spreadsheet for work in which my coworkers drag and drop data into a sheet. A report is generated on another sheet which includes a graph of the raw data.

I used "define names" for each column of data so that the correct range would be selected no matter how large the dataset is. This worked beautifully, graph would update itself every time data was changed. Then I ran VBA to scale the axes and it all got messed up

When I run the code below, The axes get scaled just like I intended them to, but now, instead of having nice cycles in the data, the graph just shows a straight horizontal line for each set of data. I checked "select data" and everything is still selected correctly, and the data is the same as it was before I hit "run," only the graph doesn't look right. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ScaleAxes
End Sub
Sub ScaleAxes()
    'With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    With ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B26").Value
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B25").Value
        .MajorUnit = 5
    End With
    'With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    With ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("C26").Value
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("C25").Value
        .MajorUnit = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

I really can't see what the problem is. The data is correct, it displayed on the graph correctly before code was run. Code works fine for scaling axes, but for some reason ruins the data inside the graph.

Comment: It'd help to know what version of Excel you're using.

Comment: And what kind of chart and what kind of data? Exactly your code works well for me with Excel 2007 and a XY scatter chart. `B2:B23` are x values, `C2:C23` are y values (=SIN(B2), ...), `B25` and `C25` are the max values from above (=MAX(B2:B23), ...) and `B26` and `C26` are the min values  (=MIN(B2:B23), ...).

Comment: @AxelRichter Yep, that's exactly what I have. Excel 2007, XY scatter chart. I do have the chart connected with smooth lines to make it look like a line chart but it is a scatter plot. The only difference in my workbook is that I have 3 sets of data on the Y axis. The data represents temperatures from 3 different thermometers, and its important to the testing procedure to have all three data sets plotted together. Other than that yours should be identical to mine.

Comment: @AxelRichter But yeah, the code works well for scaling the axes, but once I run it the data represents itself as a horizontal line, though it is supposed to be a series of smooth curves, kind of like a sine plot.

Comment: Your code does not change the chart data. If the code changes the axis scales correctly, there must be other code involved that changes the data.

Comment: @AxelRichter The code that i posted is the only code I have written... is it possible that there is unintended code hidden somewhere that is causing this? I can send it to you if that is easier. Could it be that my workbook just has too much going on and it isn't powerful enough to do all of this effectively?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data `B1:C5` and `B25:C26` with an edit into your question. And, if possible, two pictures with the chart before and after running the code.

Comment: I have some more info for you, hopefully it helps. When I manually adjust the axes to zoom out, the y-axis of the graph is right. The issue is that it is referencing the wrong x-axis values. Rather than plotting the data against the selected x-axis, it is plotting the data against the row number. So if i have a data point on the y axis corresponding to an x axis point of 55, but the x axis point is contained in row 2000 in the sheet, the data is plotted on 2000 rather than 55. Make sense? Also, the graph is correct when chart type is changed to line plot, but my code only works on scatter plot

Comment: @AxelRichter I have double checked that my data is formatted as numbers instead of text, but this had no effect. I can't seem to get the x axis to honor selected values. A line plot works great but my code doesn't work for anything besides a scatter plot so I need to either find a way to force the scatter plot to recognize my selected x-values or find a new code that can scale the axes on a line chart.